# sscanf not reading user input into struct member

Tags: c

I'm attempting to read two pieces of data (an integer and a string) from user input, in one line, and store them into a struct.

code for struct:

```
// struct for message data
typedef struct message {
    int destPort;
    char messageData[100];
} message;
```

I've allocated memory for the struct like so:

```
message* newMsg = malloc(sizeof(message));
```

Obtaining user input:

```
fgets(userInput, 100, stdin);
```

I'm using sscanf like so:

```
if(sscanf(userInput, "%d[^ ] %100[^\n]", &newMsg->destPort, newMsg->messageData) != 2) {
                printf("Error: usage is <destination port #> <message>\n");
                exit(1);
            }
```

If user inputs `"2002 hello"`, `2002` is read but `hello` isn't and therefore sscanf the `if` statement fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show a [mre] which demonstrates your problem, with sample input.

Comment: Please refer to the spec to describe which effect you expect from `"%i[^ ]"`. I am pretty sure that it has a different one.

Comment: Review [`scanf` format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). `%i[^ ]` is nonsense. The set notation is missing leading `%`, and if not intended for consumption, also the suppression `*`. Still, explain what that is *supposed* to be doing

Comment: `%d[^ ]` is just as broken as `%i[^ ]`. Again, explain what you think that is *supposed* to be doing and we can tell you how to do it corrrectly.

Comment: ```%i[^ ]``` was a typo, but yes, changing to this: ```"%d %100[^\n]"``` solved the issue. I'm updating a program I wrote a while ago, so I'm not exactly sure where I got that from. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scanf format specifier would match an input of `"2002[^ ] hello"`.
The number matches the `"%d"` (or `"%i"`). The "[^ ]" would have to be literally there, because it is not one of the format specifers from those found in the documentation.
The sample input can be matched with `"%d %100[^\n]"`, though that would require a `char messageData[101];`. Or match with  `"%d %99[^\n]"`. Both because of this part in the spec:

> Always stores a null character in addition to the characters matched (so the argument array must have room for at least width+1 characters)

(Thanks to chux for making me aware.)
It is hard to tell what you really try here, but be reminded that scanf does not support regex as you seem to try.